# How to increase the length of quick action popup

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I have a lwc component, which is used in Quick Action, the standard quick action popup length is small, I want to increase its length.
To increase the width I have used below code, but when I put the height attribute to increase the height, it shift the popup modal but doesn't increase the length.

```
.slds-modal__container{
    width: 80% !important;
    max-width: 80% !important;
}
```

Comment: Add CSS in static resource, found an [article](https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2019/01/24/how-to-increase-the-width-of-quick-action-modal-popup/) related to a similar question

Comment: This increases the width, I need to increase height as well